# DotNet New Knockout Missing In Core2

Tags: javascript, .net-core, knockout.js

When I try to run the dotnet new ASP.NET knockout generator with Core 2 on Windows, there no longer seems to be a template for Knockout.

```
PS C:\Code\Samples\KoSample> dotnet new knockout
No templates matched the input template name: knockout.
```

This was after installing the templates using the following command in terminal in VSCode:

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
```

Is that because something is not installed correctly or is Knockout simply no longer in the new version?

This [Building Single Page Applications on ASP.NET Core with JavaScriptServices](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/) article has the list of templates in the Core 1 version.

Comment: Can you give more specifics where and how you got the samples?

Comment: Added additional detail in question.

Comment: I got it working by running "dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::* " again.

 I'm not sure about the exact  sequence but the first time I installed it, I don't think I had Core2 installed.

Comment: ?... Anyway, the Asp.net Core versions with Knockout.js, Aurelia, and Vue.js are now available.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much idea of dotnet, but I have used knoockout a lot. Its not really part of dotnet. You can install it using nuget.

```
dotnet add package knockoutjs --version 3.4.2
```

or may be use the template called KnockoutSpa. Haven't tried it but thats what I can see on the github page [a link](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/rel/2.0.0/templates).

```
dotnet new KnockoutSpa
```

Comment: Thanks. The template is supposed to create an MVC Core SPA project with knockout and I was interested in how that would be structured.

Comment: Could you please try using "KnockoutSpa" instead of knockout when trying to use the template? Something like "dotnet new KnockoutSpa"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but "dotnet new KnockoutSpa" did not work.

Comment: It works if you download from https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices and start build.cmd. This updates the templates. Then run "dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::" again and finally "dotnet new knockout".

Answer (score 1):

after running the command found [here](http://dotnetnew.azurewebsites.net/template/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates.Knockout.CSharp)

`dotnet new --install "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates"`

I am seeing the knockout template 
[image]

maybe try running the command again using the quotes, the format you used looks a little different than the one i used.